# When I should check if request is is_ajax()?

Tags: django

I am a little bit confusing with [docs](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/request-response.html#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax). I can't understand real use case when I should check request to `is_ajax()`?

Comment: When you want ot return other data for an AJAX call than for another request. For example the AJAX call could return a JSON blob, and the other calls, a rendered HTML page. But personally I find it rather bad design that a view returns two different things. It is better to define two separate views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best use case of `is_ajax()` is if you want to send different data to the client depending on the type of the request.

For example, if the request is not ajax, you may want to render a full page. But if the request is ajax, you may want to only send a json response.

Example:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        return <json data>
    else:
        return render(...)
```

Comment: But usually I am sending ajax requests not for urls like `/page1` but for `/api/getdata`. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov No, you're not wrong. There are different ways to do things. Personally, I use `is_ajax` if the project is small, when I don't need to create a full-blown REST API.  For bigger projects it's definitely better to have separate views to serve different requests.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make much sense in a view IMHO - if your project is well designed, you know which views are expected to be invoked via ajax (and *exclusively* via ajax - havin the same view called either directly or via ajax is sure design smell) and which are not -, but it can be very useful in middlewares when you want to take some action depending on the request's (and eventually response) headers.